# Paste Dimensions from One Object to Another?

Tags: dimensions

I know how to copy Loc/Rot/Scale from one object to another (select the one, then the other, then choose "copy to selected")... but this option does not present itself in the Dimensions panel.  Is there another way to do this?

To be specific- I want Object A to have the same dimensions XYZ as Object B... is there a quick way to make this happen without having to type all three values in separately?  I do this a lot, so a shortcut would be helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I copy and paste dimensions to make objects the same size?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/185785/how-can-i-copy-and-paste-dimensions-to-make-objects-the-same-size)

Comment: Hey Gordon. Technically speaking, yes, but that's not exactly what I was hoping to find. With all the steps involved I might as well just manually type in the XYZ values.  I LOVE Blender but I'm so frustrated by all the things that Cinema 4D does sooooo much faster, this being a classic example.  Anyway, cheers, appreciate the comment!

Comment: There is a python script in one answer to transfer the dimension data. I'm not a scripter, but I guess people who are firm with this can make a script that might be run with a shortcut and use the selected objects as inputs... I couldn't do it, but very often people are satisfied with script answers here so I thought it might help you, too.

Comment: Added some extra info to answer there. (was for here till noticed the dupe posted by @GordonBrinkmann )  re how to use addon mentioned in  answer to create a shortcut.. .  Basically if it is shown in the UI a shortcut can be set for it.

Comment: @batFINGER Yeah great, that's what I was thinking of.

Comment: I'm very curious to know how you do this in C4D, as a reference to compare

Comment: In Cinema there are a few ways to do it.  My favorite way is to child an object to a parent and then zero all the properties of the child, which forces the child to assume all of the parent's properties.  Then when you unchild the object it still has those properties.  Super quick and easy.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing sounds like Link object data and then keep the new data to the object.
To do this, select the target object, then hold down shift and select the original object and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> and select "Link Object Data"

[image]

Now, the target object is linked to the first one's data.If you are happy with that and you want the object to be individual again, select the target and go to Object > Relation > Make sigle user > Object and data.

[image]

Hope that helps.